# Merging two JSON responses in Python?

Tags: python, json, merge, mapping

I am trying to merge two json documents to one, where I need to look for the same "id".

The first document looks like this and is named "mapping"

```
[{'examine': 'things about 10344',
  'id': 10344,
  'name': 'name10344'},
 {'examine': 'things about 20011',
  'id': 20011,
  'name': 'name20011'},
 {'examine': 'things about 3',
.
.
.
```

And the second one looks like this. Where 2,6,8 corresponds to the "id" from the first document, and is named "Data"

```
{'data': {'2': {'avgHighPrice': 159,
   'highPriceVolume': 15541889,
   'avgLowPrice': 153,
   'lowPriceVolume': 7608087},
  '6': {'avgHighPrice': 191833,
   'highPriceVolume': 95,
   'avgLowPrice': 181254,
   'lowPriceVolume': 313},
  '8': {'avgHighPrice': 193657,
   'highPriceVolume': 97,
   'avgLowPrice': 186833,
   'lowPriceVolume': 318},
.
.
.
```

In the end I would want a document that looks something like this.

```
[{'examine': 'things about 10344',
  'id': 10344,
  'name': 'name10344'
  'avgHighPrice': 123,
  'highPriceVolume': 123,
  'avgLowPrice': 123,
  'lowPriceVolume': 123},
 {'examine': 'things about 20011',
  'id': 20011,
  'name': 'name20011'
  'avgHighPrice': 123,
  'highPriceVolume': 123,
  'avgLowPrice': 123,
  'lowPriceVolume': 123},
 {'examine': 'things about...',
.
.
.
```

I tried creating a new directory and adding things to it, but Python wont let me add things to the directory like this.

```
mydict = {}
x = mapping[0]['id']
mydict[x] = data ['data'][x],mapping[0]
```

Comment: Your `data` dict format is wrong. Missing `{`.
Fix it and update your question.

Comment: I do not understand the correlation between `2, 6, 8` and the `id`. Can you explain with clear examples how these are linked? Remember, the better the question, the better the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure that there is data for each `id` in mapping, you can do this:

```py
merged = []
for m in mapping:
    merged.append({**data['data'][str(m['id'])], **m})
```

It loops through the mapping data to find the corresponding data entry and uses the dict-merge syntax to combine the two. For more on merging dicts, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression).

If you don't have data for each mapping, you have to pull the `append(...)` statement apart and add some validation.